# How to find last date all record in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date

how can i find last date record in MySQL.
i have this current date record but if i want to get a data of last day (not yesterday). it is possible to get last date of record in MySQL.

my current date record are there (28-11-2017)..
and i want last date of record which is (25-11-2017)
between this 25 to 28 there is no data . i want this last date record.

ex.

```
id       DATE      PRODUCT_ID
1    2017-11-25      11
2    2017-11-25      12
3    2017-11-24      6
```

so last date in my table will be 25. how can i get all record of that date.

link for current date table: [current table](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sq4v2ZrZ5Co3dclxO8Fc1M0muvIPSv2A)

Comment: I think `select date from table order by date desc limit 1` will give you the last date.

Comment: @chris85 Yes but that would only give a single record (which perhaps is what the OP actually wants).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yea, that's what my thinking was; not sure though what the full intent of this is though.

Comment: i just edited my question

Comment: @RaymondNijland Even if the dates are actually stored as text, ordering by date should still work as the dates are in an ISO format.

Comment: I know @TimBiegeleisen also date functions and INTERVAL should work on that ISO format... i've posted `Please include the SHOW CREATE TABLE [table_name]` in the wrong SO thread.

Comment: @RaymondNijland They all sort of look the same after a while :-)

Comment: You should use @TimBiegeleisen answer and put a `WHERE DATE < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` that should hold up to your question after the last edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to compare the date of each record against a non correlated subquery which finds the most recent date in the table.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM yourTable);
```

If you are certain that there is only one latest date, or you can live with just a single record in the event of ties, then MySQL offers an even simpler option:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE FROM your_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will get you the last date.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it should be `ORDER BY DATE DESC` I think.

Comment: id is the auto_increment field so i need to order it by `id` to get the last one. If i order it by DATE i don't know if i get the last date for sure as i don't know the date formats that are inserted

Comment: I didn't vote either but look at the sample data, if you go by `id` you'll get `2017-11-24`, not `2017-11-25` as OP states they need.

Comment: "as i don't know the date formats that are inserted ' @pr1nc3 if you use DATE datatype on date you always can trust the format to be the same.. DATE datatype always has the format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: The other problem with assuming that auto increment always correlates with date is that the values can sometimes be interrupted for a number of reasons.